# java column not found exception when getting maximum value from sql database column

Tags: java, sql, exception

I always get an exception runnung  this method. it is supposed to get the maximum value of the column in the database table. here's my code:

```
private void genConNum(){
        try {
            String sql = "select max(contrno) from cis";
            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next()){
                cont = rs.getString("contrno");
                num = Integer.parseInt(cont);
                num = num + 1;
                cont = String.valueOf(num);
                ContractNo.setText(cont);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to generate Contract Number\n"+ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

and here's the stacktrace

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'contrno' not found.
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:910)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.findColumn(ResultSet.java:987)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getString(ResultSet.java:5584)
at client.AddCon.genConNum(AddCon.java:85)
at client.AddCon.access$1300(AddCon.java:20)
at client.AddCon$4.actionPerformed(AddCon.java:286)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

but the column EXISTS in the database itself. i tried to query the database with the same statement but in the dbms it works. I wonder why it won't work in java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your sql to :

```
String sql = "select max(contrno) contrno from cis";
```

Comment: Additionally, you can use a proper alias (i.e. `String sql = "select max(contrno) as max_contrno from cis";`) and then use `cont = rs.getInt("max_contrno");` instead of manually parsing a string.

Answer (score 1):

Change the sql as @Grisha has suggested.If you do not want to change sql then

Change `cont =rs.getString("contrno");` to `cont =rs.getString("max(contrno)");`

Answer (score 0):

Could simplify the whole thing by doing this:

```
private void genConNum(){
        try {
            String sql = "select (max(contrno)+1) as max_val from cis";
            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next()){
                ContractNo.setText(rs.getString("max_val"));
            }  
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to generate Contract Number\n"+ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I changed the query to do the addition step for you so all you have to do is pull out the value as a `String` and set it on your text field.